# Show $\forall \delta > 0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is in the title, but I have no idea how to solve it, so a few hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In fact, you won't prove it because it is an axiom.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the statement is false. Then we have some $\delta>0$ such that $\delta^{-1}>n$ for all $n$. This contradicts the Archimedean property. Assuming $\mathbb{R}$ is defined axiomatically, this property is easily derived as a consequence of the least upper bound axiom.

Comment: But isn't the original statement the archimedian property itself?

Answer (score -1):

Given $\delta$, let $k = \frac{1}{\delta}$

$$\delta = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\delta}} = \frac{1}{k}$$

Consider $ \frac{1}{\lfloor k+1 \rfloor}$.